# deleteMany increases index size

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-indexes

I have a collection with 100,000 documents, with index totalling 80MB. Then I dropped all documents by running:

```
col.deleteMany({})
```

After the operation, the index size increased to 190.46MB.

What explains this?

EDITED:

And now it has settled at 110MB.

Comment: I am not sure how the space increased, but you can try compact command to release unused space. https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/command/compact/

Comment: Please take a backup before, if the data is crucial.